# Using DOMParser in XML to get attribute using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml, domparser

I have an XML file that I get from an API and a small section is:

```
       <Abstract>
            <AbstractText Label="BACKGROUND">A large ...</AbstractText>
            <AbstractText Label="METHODS">We modeled....</AbstractText>
            <AbstractText Label="RESULTS">Mammary glands ... </AbstractText>
            <AbstractText Label="CONCLUSIONS">We report...</AbstractText>
        </Abstract>
```

My JavaScript code is:

```
      parser = new DOMParser();
      xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(response.data, "text/xml");
      const abstracts = xmlDoc.querySelectorAll("AbstractText");
```

and by using

```
        abstracts.forEach(a => {         
        abstract_text += a.innerHTML;
        abstract_text += "<br /><br />";
      });
```

I can read all of the text.  My problem is I can't get the Label value.  I've tried

```
    let x = a.attribute("Label").nodeValue;
```

and

```
       let x = a.attribute("Label");
```

both as attribute as attributes .

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `a.getAttribute('Label')` you wanted

Here's one way to do it

```js
const xml = `<Abstract>
    <AbstractText Label="BACKGROUND">A large ...</AbstractText>
    <AbstractText Label="METHODS">We modeled....</AbstractText>
    <AbstractText Label="RESULTS">Mammary glands ... </AbstractText>
    <AbstractText Label="CONCLUSIONS">We report...</AbstractText>
</Abstract>`;

parser = new DOMParser();
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");
const abstracts = xmlDoc.querySelectorAll("AbstractText");

abstracts.forEach(a => {
  console.log(a.textContent, a.getAttribute('Label'));
});
```

You could also

```
a.attributes['Label'].nodeValue
a.attributes.Label.nodeValue
a.attributes['Label'].textContent
a.attributes.Label.textContent
```